# RuntimeException: at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$5@19.0.2:379

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-vitals

I got below error on Android vitals on Play store from Samsung Galaxy S10(beyond1q) running on Android 9. I got more than a 3.5K crashes in the last 7 days.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$5(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.2:379) 
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$Lambda$5.run (Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7037)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)


Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow (Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteConnection.java:1060)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow (SQLiteSession.java:836)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow (SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow (SQLiteCursor.java:169)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove (SQLiteCursor.java:131)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition (AbstractCursor.java:237)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext (AbstractCursor.java:269)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteLruReferenceDelegate.removeOrphanedDocuments
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.removeOrphanedDocuments
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.runGarbageCollection
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.collect
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$collectGarbage$9
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore$$Lambda$10.get (Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.collectGarbage
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector$Scheduler.lambda$scheduleGC$0
at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector$Scheduler$$Lambda$1.run (Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask.handleDelayElapsed
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask.access$lambda$0 (Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask$$Lambda$1.run (Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:459)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

app-level Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

Project Gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

**Note** We have also other users that use the same device but didn't face any issue.

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException:` You aren't storing files in your SQL database, are you?

Comment: If you have a bug report for the Cloud Firestore Android SDK, please post it to GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-firestore

Comment: @Zun I'm not storing any file in the SQL database.